# Error: (SystemJS) Base is not defined in angularr 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 2, And want to Find a parent component of known type. But got this error:

**Error: (SystemJS) Base is not defined.**

**ReferenceError: Base is not defined**

please suggest what I am doing wrong.

**parent-finder.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'alex',
  template: `
    <div class="a">
      <h3>{{name}}</h3>
      <cathy></cathy>
      <craig></craig>
    </div>`,

})
export class AlexComponent extends Base
{
  name= 'Alex';
}



@Component({
  selector: 'cathy',
  template: `
  <div class="c">
    <h3>Cathy</h3>
    {{alex ? 'Found' : 'Did not find'}} Alex via the component class.<br>
  </div>`
})
export class CathyComponent {
  constructor( @Optional() public alex: AlexComponent ) { }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'craig',
  template: `
  <div class="c">
    <h3>Craig</h3>
    {{alex ? 'Found' : 'Did not find'}} Alex via the base class.
  </div>`
})
export class CraigComponent {
  constructor( @Optional() public alex: Base ) { }
}
```

Comment: You need to import { Base } from somewhere. Did you forget an import?

Comment: Thanks, let me add.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer,should Add Base Class and Parent Class.

```
export abstract class Base   { name = 'Count Basie'; }
export abstract class Parent { name: string;         }
```